# How to link additional disk for photos linked with my project

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, storage

I'm working on my production; it's based on PHP Laravel framework.

Is there anyway to add additional disk and link it to my project to upload images, videos, data etc. Just to use it as storage.

How to do that ? Is there better idea like to make new VM with higher HD ?

Comment: Laravel supports any number of file systems located locally and in the cloud. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem What is **higher HD**? If you mean to resize the virtual machine virtual disk larger, consult the documentation. Your question does not even mention the virtualization software that you are using. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My project is on the server "GCP VM Centos" and it works fine .. But in the future, can I add another independent hard disk for the images away from the hard disk that contains the main project "PHP Laravel" , and how is this linking idea?

Comment: Yes, you can add another disk to your Compute Engine VM instance. You will need to partition and format a partition with a file system such as EXT4. Using the Laravel link you can then create a Laravel filesystem to store files, images, etc. What do you mean by **how is this linking idea**?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two choices here:

1. You can simply [create a new persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) and [attach it to your existing VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk). Then you need to format it (using a filesystem of your choice) and mount it. After that you're ready to go (just make sure it will be mounted automatically at boot). You may choose any size from 10GB up to 64TB. You can also select the disk type (HDD, balanced, SSD) but since you mentioned images then simple HDD will probably be the best choice for you but have a look at the [disk storage comparison documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#introduction) to find the best one for you.
2. Another approach is to create a [storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) and then mount it as a file storage using [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) drivers. I've found this tutorial to show you how to do [mount a storage bucket in Linux](https://medium.com/@antrixsh/how-to-mount-cloud-storage-bucket-with-gcp-compute-engine-ba7c95ad5349).

Price-wise using a storage bucket will usually cost you half of what the persistent disk would.

Persistent disk storage will be faster on the other hand - so you need to figure out if the bucket is sufficient and if not use the disk.

Another advantage of using the disk is a lot easier backup - just create a disk snapshot (you don't need to stop the machine) - it's relatively quick process. In case you needed to do some recovery - using disk will save you some time.

Usefull docs:

- [GCP bucket pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#price-tables)
- [GCP persisten disk pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/disks-image-pricing#disk)
- [GCP cost calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)